# Section attribute within template

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to ask why this doesn't relocate the data into the desired section,

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Retram {
  static T data;

  inline auto operator=(const T& other) {
    data = other;
    return *this;
  }

  operator auto &() const {
    return data;
  }

  operator auto *() const {
    return &data;
  }
};

template <typename T>
__attribute__((section(".retram"))) T Retram<T>::data = T();
```

when this does

```cpp
struct Retram {
  static int data;

  inline auto operator=(const int& other) {
    data = other;
    return *this;
  }

  operator auto &() const {
    return data;
  }

  operator auto *() const {
    return &data;
  }
};

__attribute__((section(".retram"))) int Retram::data = int();
```

You are welcome to provide alternate pretty solutions, but I'd still like to understand why this doesn't work.

Both compile, but the template version will NOT relocate the symbol as desired.

Minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
Retram<int> my_retram_value;
my_retram_value = 42;

printf("retram value: %i\n", *my_retram_value);
```

Comment: whats the meaning of "doesn't work" ? What is the code supposed to do and how does it fail to do so?

Comment: I caught the "doesn't work" myself and edited straight away. It was sort of ambiguous, admittedly.

Comment: You should fix the text. It now says: "I'd like to ask why this doesnt work [....] Both compile and work". How do you know that the symbols are relocated / not relocated?

Comment: By checking for its existence in the section .retram

Comment: are you actually instantiating the template?

Comment: Yes, of course. Not shown in example though.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Templates are inline by default.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Instantiating a variable, setting and using it? I thought it too trivial, but I've updated.

Comment: @lorro You're thinking that the data access is optimized out?

Comment: gcc ignores attributes in templates generally. This is a bug for many many years now. Nobody seems to be interested to fix it. There are more than 10 open bug reports! https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=SUSPENDED&bug_status=WAITING&bug_status=REOPENED&cf_known_to_fail_type=allwords&cf_known_to_work_type=allwords&query_format=advanced&short_desc=attribute%20template&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr

Comment: @Klaus That explains it then - thank you! :D Please post as an answer, so I can mark it as the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gcc ignores attributes in templates generally. This is a know bug for many years now. There are more than 10 open bug reports related to this issue. See [bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=SUSPENDED&bug_status=WAITING&bug_status=REOPENED&cf_known_to_fail_type=allwords&cf_known_to_work_type=allwords&query_format=advanced&short_desc=attribute%20template&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr). The problem affects not only member functions but also variable templates and free template functions.

Someone has started to work on it but after running in trouble with `-flto` he gave up. [comments for patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70435) Currently it seems that there is nobody interested in fixing this very old issue.

Especially for embedded devices this is a real show stopper. This makes it impossible to place templated data to flash or makes it impossible to run interrupt handlers in templated code and much more.

People running again on one of the bugs should make a comment in the bug report for the fields "Known to fail" and "Last confirmed". Maybe this makes it visible that the problem persists and the fix is interesting for some more people. But as always in open source projects: Products get better by helping them. I have no experience on gcc development, sorry :-)

Comment: is the situation better with clang?

Comment: @AntonKrug: Why you ask me? You simply should try it out and may report it here! BTW: If you take a look at  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88061 it seems to be fixed with gcc 14. Can you confirm?